# Why do I get an error "The method ... is undefined for the type..."?

Tags: java, string, jsp, methods, types

I've build a method which takes strings as input parameter. In my `index.jsp` page, I retrieve a GET-variable from the URL using `request.getParameter()`. Now, I want to call the aforementioned method on this string, but I get a compiler error saying:

> The method `<method name>`(String) is undefined for the type `__2F_<webapp name>_2F_src_2F_main_2F_webapp_2F_index_2E_jsp`".

Does anyone know why I get this error and how I can get rid of it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My code is rather lengthy, but I think this is relevant code:

```
categorie = request.getParameter("categorie");

if (categorie.equals("")) {
    categorie = "Category;";
}

ArrayList<String> categorieen = queryCategories(categorie);
```

Comment: can you post the content of the JSP page?

Comment: this code is placed inside a JSP page using scriptlets?

Comment: That is correct. I know scriptlets suck, but it is good enough for our purpose. Could the error come from using scriptlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `ArrayList<String> categorieen = queryCategories(categorie);` and you did not define **queryCategories** method. Since the JSP page is compiled into a big servlet class, it tries to locate **queryCategories** method as member of that class and it could not find it.

Comment: At the top of the .jsp page I import the class CategoryDAO.java, like this: <%@ page import="database.CategoryDAO" %>. In that class, I have defined the function queryCategories(String categorie)

Comment: new  you have to do new CategoryDAO().queryCategories(...). Just importing the class does not mean that their methods are becoming methods of the new class.

Comment: It's a static method.

Comment: Even that. You need to call it: CategoryDAO.queryCategories(..).

Comment: Ah I'm stupid. I had to prefix it with CategoryDAO.queryCategories(). Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Very little information. Where is your app deployed? From what I gather, it seems you either haven't restarted the deployed app or have not replaced the changed class file and haven't set some sort of "development mode" on wherein you don't require a restart for a Jsp modification.

Just replace the `.jsp` and `JSP_NAME.class` file.